# Are you able to name a React hook const the same as an already defined const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to assign my Provider store prop to my Routes hook store, but I'm also creating a store in the function, so I have an issue with duplicated variables. Is there a way to declare a hook with the same const name as an already defined const?

```
  const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  sessionService.initSessionService(store);
  store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('store.getState()', store.getState());
  });
  const [store] = useState();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter className="router">
```

defining const [store] = useState(); throws an error of: 
Identifier 'store' has already been declared.

You are able to define a state in a Class, and have it have the same identifier as a const, but are we not able to do that using hooks? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since they are part of the same function here they are in the same namespace, so no you cannot name them the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If they both declared on the same block (`{}`) then no, because `const` (and `let`) is [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

If they "live" on a different block though, its fine:

```js
function foo() {
  {
    const x = 1;
  }
  const x = 2
  console.log('x is ', x)
}

foo()
```